# c# creating opacity on UI elements rendering from xml

Tags: c#, .net, deserialization, silverlight-5.0, xml-deserialization

i am silverligth c# developer and am badly stuck  in finding a way to solve a situation. 
My situation is i have a xml like :

```
<a>
  <name>a_name</name>
  <type>ComboBox</type>
<items>
  <item>1</item>
<item>2</item>
  </items>
  <disables>
  <disable>b_name<disable>
  </disables>
</a>

<a>
  <name>b_name</name>
  <type>TextBlock</type>
</a>

<a>
  <name>c_name</name>
  <type>TextBlock</type>
</a>
```

Situation is like that this xml contains two UI elements . One is combobox and anotherone is textblock in different rows.
When i select "1" from combobox (you can see there are two items "1" and "2")If i select "1" it should disappear(disppear mean create opacity over textblock) whose name is "b_name" but "c_name" is still visible yet.And when i select "2" it must create opacity over "textblock" whose name is "c_name" whereas "b_name" is still visible now.

My try to do so :

I know i have to deserialize it and create the object of a[i] class. Suppose i do so like this:

ObjectObtained a[i] where is the count of number of  present.

But how to proceed further to make the opacity work on comboclick events that i have no idea.

Could some one please give me the basic idea about how to do it ? (I dont need implementation , just therotical in short i want to know how to do)

Currently i have implemented is something liek this which creates 1 combo box in a row and two textblocks in another row like this:

```
ObjectObtained = a[loopCount] ;
switch (ObjectObtained.type) 
  {      
  case "ComboBox":
    rowGrid = generateComboBox(ObjectObtained); //it creates combo box
    break;      
  case "TextBlock":
    rowGrid = generateTextBlock(ObjectObtained); //it creates textblock
    break;      
  }
  Grid.SetRow(rowGrid, loopCount);
  bigGrid.Children.Add(rowGrid);
  loopCount++;
```

**But i dont know how to create opacity on the different textbocks on different select by combobox ? Please help me in that i am stuck very badly and Is it possible to achieve this ?**

I am working on a project and there i have this situation where i am obliged to do it programatically. Could you please give me some idea how to implement it. I mean how to vary opacity on the selection change of combo box ? I couldnt find any logic yet . and badly stuck here. And do you think it is possible to achieve ? My unability to do it create suspection iin me now after long time that it is possible to acvhieve or not

Comment: This is a really bad way to implement this, which completely ignores all the advantages of XAML-based technologies and attempts to use them as if they were winforms or whatever other archaic UI framework. I strongly recommend an entire refactoring to do this **Properly** by using proper XAML and DataBinding.

Comment: @HighCore you are right but ther are no other options given to me. And do you think that is it possible to implement to do what i am trying to achieve programatically ? I just need a logic to implement. Could you please help me ? I am stuck badly here.

Comment: Yes. It should be possible, however it will require a very cumbersome approach, since you are creating all these elements in procedural code rather than proper XAML. What is the type of `rowGrid`?

Comment: Grid rowGrid. It is auto for row . I mean each UI element is displayed  ina row. I know the approach used will be difficult but i still couldn't get anything to achieve it. so need someone experienced's helps. Could you please help mein developing logic for it ?

Comment: The lack of proper state storage (ViewModel) of your UI elements will make this task really difficult. When you create the ComboBox, you will have to either Bind it's `SelectedItem` property to *something* (saying *something* since you have no ViewModel) or hook the ComboBox's `SelectionChanged` event to some code which in turn does whatever you need to other UI elements.

Comment: I DO LIKE THIS: in generateComboBox()definition:   cb.SelectionChanged += (o, e) =>
            {
               But How to call GenerateTextBox(); function on disable b_name and c_name  basis because it is in another Case Condition 
            }; (here cb is ComboBox cb = new ComboBox();)

Comment: generateComboBox()definition: cb.SelectionChanged += (o, e) => { But How to call GenerateTextBox(); function on disable b_name and c_name basis because it is in another Case Condition }; (here cb is ComboBox cb = new ComboBox();)

Comment: @HighCore could you found some way to achieve the target ? Do you still say it is possible to do ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55384/discussion-between-user234839-and-highcore).

Comment: @HighCore what do you say ?